# Insert Fiori elements app into freestyle application

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori, sap-web-ide

I'm fairly new to UI5 and I'd like to know if it's possible to have a SAP UI5 application (with views, controllers etc.) and insert a Fiori elements page (for instance a List Report or a Worklist/Object page) as a view into said application?
The list report app would build its UI using annotations from an odata service.
The whole app would run outside of the Fiori Launchpad.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to insert the whole Fiori elements app as a component into the other application.

Comment: do you have a blog or something where you found it? Would like to know a bit more of this topic